# Python: replace data frame values based on column name and conditional

Tags: python, dataframe

Let’s say we have a data frame with 6 columns. For a subset of 3 of those columns we want to change instances of 3 to 1. Can you suggest an elegant way to do so?
Simply writing a line like:

```
df['A'][df.A == 3] = 1
```

is inefficient in my real data as the dimensions are much larger (like changing 50 out of 200 variables).

Perhaps we could work on this example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(100, 6)), columns=list('ABCDEF'))
```

Where we want to change values of 3 to 1 in columns A, B, and C. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the subset of columns and use `loc` for assignment.

```
subset cols = ['A', 'B', 'C']  # For example.
for col in subset_cols:
    df.loc[df[col] == 3, col] = 1
```